# How to get the acutal repository url of a go package

Tags: go

For example, we can use `go get k8s.io/client-go` to install the go package but is there a way to figure out the source code URL is actually https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go? Because if I visit k8s.io/client-go directly it shows 404.

How does the go client figure out where the source code is in this example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Command go: Remote import paths:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths)

> Certain import paths also describe how to obtain the source code for the package using a revision control system.
>
> ... For code hosted on other servers, import paths may either be qualified with the version control type, or the go tool can dynamically fetch the import path over https/http and discover where the code resides from a `<meta>` tag in the HTML.
>
> ... If the import path is not a known code hosting site and also lacks a version control qualifier, the go tool attempts to fetch the import over https/http and looks for a  tag in the document's HTML `<head>`.
>
> The meta tag has the form:
> `<meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix vcs repo-root">`
>
> The import-prefix is the import path corresponding to the repository root. It must be a prefix or an exact match of the package being fetched with "go get". If it's not an exact match, another http request is made at the prefix to verify the `<meta>` tags match.

For example in your case the `go` tool will query `https://k8s.io/client-go?go-get=1`. Checking it ourselves:

```
curl https://k8s.io/client-go?go-get=1
```

Response:

```
<html><head>
    <meta name="go-import"
          content="k8s.io/client-go
                   git https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go">
    <meta name="go-source"
          content="k8s.io/client-go
                   https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go
                   https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master{/dir}
                   https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master{/dir}/{file}#L{line}">
</head></html>
```

As you can see, the response HTML document clearly indicates the code is available at `github.com/kubernetes/client-go`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you take a look at these two? https://gopkg.in/yaml.v3?go-get=1 and https://honnef.co/go/tools?go-get=1   The actual Github link for the first one is actually in `go-source` meta, but the second has no `go-source` meta

Comment: @xinyi As the documentation states, `go-import` is what matters. The first one has meta tag: `content="gopkg.in/yaml.v3 git https://gopkg.in/yaml.v3"`. If you execute `git clone https://gopkg.in/yaml.v3`, you get your package.

Comment: @xinyi The `go-source` meta tag is used to specify links to source code on services not known to GoDoc.org. See [this](https://github.com/golang/gddo/wiki/Source-Code-Links) for more details.